# CDATA in my .xml is creating orphan /> closing tag in <body>

Tags: magento-1.9, local.xml, parent-child-theme

When I made my child theme, I wanted to extend the local.xml of the parent theme, so instead of creating my own local.xml (which would replace the parent one instead of extending it), I created a customlocal.xml and added it via my theme.xml. However, my new CSS file is loading first before all other css files, which is really dumb for a parent-child theming scheme. I found this [post](http://www.coderblog.de/magento-1-9-infinite-theme-inheritance-child-css-not-rendered-last/)that explained that xml with if statements are loaded afterward, so I put an empty if statement in my xml:

```
        <action method="addCss">
            <stylesheet>css/mycustomcss.css</stylesheet>
            <if><![CDATA[<!--[]><!-->]]></if>
        </action>
```

This did work and load my CSS after the parent themes, but now I'm getting an orphan html closing tag right after my :

```
<body class="catalog-product-view" cz-shortcut-listen="true">/&gt;
```

The /&gt renders as /> on the page, before the header and all other content. Does anyone know how I correctly use an empty CDATA to get my css to load in the expected position?

PS also, in my css link in the head, `<!--[]=""` is being added in at the end:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/mylift/store/skin/frontend/custom/default/css/mycustomcss.css" <!--[]="">
```

and `<!---->`is also showing up right before the closing tag of the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `addItem` and `addCss` methods have different signatures.  You would need to look at `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head` to see the differences and which parameters are required and which are optional.  The XML nodes of the action follow the same rules as PHP:  if you want to "skip" a parameter, you still need to include it but leave it empty.

The `addCss` method takes two parameters: the style sheet path and parameters.

```
/**
 * Add CSS file to HEAD entity
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $params
 * @return Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
 */
public function addCss($name, $params = "")
```

The `addItem` takes quite a few parameters as it needs to support different elements like scripts, style sheets and meta elements.

```
/**
 * Add HEAD Item
 *
 * Allowed types:
 *  - js
 *  - js_css
 *  - skin_js
 *  - skin_css
 *  - rss
 *
 * @param string $type
 * @param string $name
 * @param string $params
 * @param string $if
 * @param string $cond
 * @return Mage_Page_Block_Html_Head
 */
public function addItem($type, $name, $params=null, $if=null, $cond=null)
```

So the only way to add a style sheet with an empty if statement is to use the `addItem` method.

As an alternative I've implemented a customization of this class which adds the functionality to insert an element before/after another element.  This requires a module and some knowledge of how Magento keeps the scripts array, but is fairly easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out I was missing a

```
<params/>
```

in my xml, that I guess closes out the head tag. For some reason, I also needed to use the method "addItem" and specify the type as css, rather than addCss. The complete XML looks like this:

```
<reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem">
         <type>skin_css</type>
         <name>css/mycustomcss.css</name>
         <params/>
         <if><![CDATA[<!--[]><!-->]]></if>
    </action>
 </reference>
```

This will **not work**:

```
<reference name="head">
   <action method="addCss">
        <stylesheet>css/mycustomcss.css</stylesheet>
        <params/>
        <if><![CDATA[<!--[]><!-->]]></if>
    </action>
</reference>
```